# Building VC++ project on new computer - system headers not found

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

After frying a mother board, I am trying to compile a VC++ project on a new computer. The old computer had Windows 7 Home, the new one has Windows 7 Professional. I have installed the proper SDK (v 8.1). I am using the same compiler and IDE (VC++ 2017 under Visual Studio), but possibly a later revision of each.

The compiler is not finding system include file "corecrt.h". Indeed, it does not seem to be anywhere on the new computer. It is referenced in "crtdef.h" which is in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include"

Where is "corecrt.h" supposed to be, and why didn't I get it when I installed Visual Studio? Or is the compiler finding an obsolete version of crtdef.h?

EDIT: I still do not know why installing SDK 8.1 was not sufficient, but I was able to get it to compile by right-clicking on the solution, selecting "retarget solution" and taking the default "OK", which was 10-point-something.

Comment: You probably failed to install all of the C and C++ development tools when you installed Visual Studio. If I remember correctly, they're not checked by default. Sounds like you may also need to install the Windows SDK.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I installed SDK 8.1. How do I install the C/C++ development tools? When I downloaded the installer for Visual Studio, I clicked on the C++ box. Is that what you mean?